# "could not connect to server: No such file or directory" Django deploy to Heroku Error

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

Im facing this problem when i tried to deploy Django Rest Framework App to Heroku:

```
Exception Type: OperationalError at /
Exception Value: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This Error is from Heroku, i have a .travis.yml to check errors before deploying on github, and every test went well. The deploy Building on Heroku went well, so this error is coming from the Django Debugger on Heroku App.

This is my **Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn wardogs.wsgi --log-file -
```

I dont know what i have to show you becouse the error is not coming from any local directories.
I read on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336844/error-when-run-migrations-on-heroku-postgresql-with-rails-5) that i should execute this command:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql
```

but the error persist. What should i do?

**settings.py** DATABASES:

```py
urllib.parse.uses_netloc.append('postgres')
urllib.parse.uses_netloc.append('mysql')

try:
    if 'DATABASES' not in locals():
        DATABASES = {}

    if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
        url = urllib.parse.urlparse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
        # Ensure default database exists.
        DATABASES['default'] = DATABASES.get('default', {})
        # Update with environment configuration.
        DATABASES['default'].update({
            'NAME': url.path[1:],
            'USER': url.username,
            'PASSWORD': url.password,
            'HOST': url.hostname,
            'PORT': url.port,
        })
        if url.scheme == 'postgres':
            DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.postgresql'

        if url.scheme == 'mysql':
            DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.mysql'
            
except Exception:
    print('Unexpected error:', sys.exc_info() )
```

**Edit:**
Found the solution!. This is my **setting.DATABASE**:

```
POSTGRES_URL = "HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_DBNAME_URL"

import dj_database_url

if 'DATABASES' not in locals():
    DATABASES = {}
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://(username):(password)@localhost:5432/db_name')

if POSTGRES_URL in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {}
    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ[POSTGRES_URL])
```

Then i run:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django with PostgreSQL app on Heroku not synching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321064/django-with-postgresql-app-on-heroku-not-synching)

Comment: Provisioning a database isn't enough. You need to tell Django to _use it_.

Comment: Hi @Chris, i edited my question to show you my **DATABASEs** settings. ¿Are you refering to those setting when you say i need to tell Django what database to use?

Comment: What's the deal with that `DATABASE` variable? Why are you setting it to `2` and then immediately doing a conditional on whether its value is `2`? In any case, this isn't how you connect to PostgreSQL on Heroku. You need to use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable [as documented](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres) and described in the duplicate I suggested.

Comment: I use that becouse sometimes i use sqlite locally. Okay so i edited my database settings ( Look at **setting.py** DATABASES ),  and now, when i run test on local, it says `settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value.`. In any case, **'DATABASE_URL'** should be named as that?, i dont think i have to call it as Heroku DATABASE_URL

Comment: Stop over-complicating this. Don't use SQLite "sometimes", and don't put MySQL or anything else in there without a very good reason. Use the same database server in development as you plan to use in production. These things aren't drop-in replacements for each other. Swapping them in and out is going to cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: Either use `DATABASE_URL` directly (you can set this manually in your development environment, no need for a conditional) or check out [`dj-database-url`](https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/).

Comment: Chris it works, o my god. Genius men, thanks!.